# How to show multi-line HTML code block with Jade

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm using Jade with Node js and want to show an HTML code block in a bootstrap  web-page.

I tried this one

```
  p
    | Copy and paste the following HTML code in a web page.

  code
    | <div class="container">
    |    <iframe src="http://ea-studio.forexsb.com"
    |         style="width: 100%; min-height: 1500px" >
    |    </iframe>
    | </div>
```

But instead of showing the code, it executed it. The result was really funny. My app integrated in itself :) but this was not my intention.

What is the Jade way of showing multi-line source code?

**Edit:**

Escaping the HTML shows the code, but in a single line:

```
  code
    | &lt;div class=&quot;container&quot;&gt;
    |    &lt;iframe src=&quot;http://ea-studio.forexsb.com&quot;
    |         style=&quot;width: 100%; min-height: 1500px&quot; &gt;
    |    &lt;/iframe&gt;
    | &lt;/div&gt;
```

Produces:

```
<div class="container"> <iframe src="http://ea-studio.forexsb.com" style="width: 100%; min-height: 1500px" > </iframe> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
p.
  Copy and paste the following HTML code in a web page.

pre
  code
    | &lt;div class="container">
    |    &lt;iframe src="http://ea-studio.forexsb.com"
    |         style="width: 100%; min-height: 1500px">
    |    &lt;/iframe>
    | &lt;/div>
```

[image]

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/wGOeeo?editors=1000

Comment: Excellent. I found out that only `pre` tag is enough without `code` tag.